# Computable set and its first projection

Tags: algorithms

I got stuck at one of the problems, related to the algorithms theory.

How to build a computable set $B \subset N$ so that the first projecton of it (defined as $pr_{1}= \{ x | \exists y (x, y) \in B \}$ is noncomputable?

I suppose that this is related to the problem of Turing machine's stoppage, but i have no thoughtful ideas how to transorm it in a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the set

$$\Big\{\big\langle \langle I, T\rangle, R \big\rangle \ \Big|\ R \text{ is the (finite) run of Turing machine }T\text{ on input } I\Big\}.$$

Certainly we can decide in finite time whether $R$ is a proper run of $T$ on $I$, but to check whether $\langle I,T\rangle$ stops is undecidable.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Could you also indicate, by what do you mean "a proper run of $T$ on $I$" ?

As i understood: for instance, we can establish, if a TM stops after a number of steps or not, but we can't actually understand if TM stops on input $I$ or not.
Am i right?

Comment: @Arteom $R$ might be some garbage (i.e. it's not a run of $T$), but $R$ could also be a run of $T$, but not matching $I$, e.g. ending in a non-terminating state (prefix of a run), etc. We need that $R$ is the whole run of $T$ on $I$, from beginning to termination; only then it is a proof that $T$ stops on $I$.